# Different behaviour of injected fields in unit test and deployed version

Tags: spring, spring-boot, dependency-injection, lombok

I am new in lombok and spring and I have one issue which I am trying to understand. Firstly my code was design as below and then I modified it because I needed to have a setter.After that all tests passed. But after deployment I started to get null pointer exception for the service field.

So my question is why I am getting null pointer exception? I think after removing final keyword lombok does not create constructor for that field. But still I do not understand why it did not fail on unit tests if that is the reason? And what is the solution for it ?

This is the first version which works.

```
 @Component
    @RequiredArgsConstructor
    public class MyClass{
        
        private final MyServiceservice service; 
        private final MyOtherService otherservice;
    
    }
```

This the version after update and where service field is null.

```
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class MyClass{
    
    @Setter
    private MyServiceservice service; 
    private final MyOtherService otherservice;

}
```

Comment: When there is on ly a single constructor spring will use that for autowiring. Lombok will generate that for `final` fields in your case. For the non-`final` field it won't be generated and that field will never be set (as there is no`@Autowired` on the setter and thus nothing for Spring to know it should inject that).

Comment: I just switched RequiredArgsConstructor to @AllArgsConstructor. But still I do not understand why it does not fail during unit/integration tests.

Comment: Without seeing your tests that is impossible to answer.